# jquery dialog over iframe containing java applet

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, applet

Part of our solution makes use of a viewer which is a java applet.  I get that next-to-nothing can be displayed on top of it but I have elements such as jquery dialogs that *have* to be displayed over it.

I have tried adding bgiframe and altering the code to be applied for all version of IE since we are using IE 8 in this specific instance.  It didn't work properly.

The thing is that I need the iframe shim to be moved around, resized, and have it's visibility set along with the element it is linked to.

Are there any plug-ins to do this?  If nothing exists I will need to develop one :(

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create my own plug-in to do this.